# Listview run so lag while loading 20 image from internet

Tags: android, listview, xamarin, xamarin.android

So I've been trying to make it asynchronously download the images.my app run slow and lag and delay

```html
public override View GetView(int position, View convertView,ViewGroup parent)
       {
        View view = convertView ?? _inflater.Inflate (Resource.Layout.textViewItems, parent, false);

        
        if (track.artwork_url != null) {


         var imageBitmap = GetImageBitmapFromUrl(track.artwork_url);
         if (imageBitmap != null && imageBitmap.Length > 0) {
          var converterImage = BitmapFactory.DecodeByteArray (imageBitmap, 0, imageBitmap.Length);
          viewHolder.Image.SetImageBitmap(converterImage);
         }

        } else {
         viewHolder.Image.SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.img1);
        }


        return view;
       }

public static byte[] GetImageBitmapFromUrl(string url)
  {
   byte [] imageBitmap = null;

   using (var webClient = new WebClient())
   {
    var imageBytes = webClient.DownloadData(url);

    imageBitmap = imageBytes;
   }


   return imageBitmap;
 }
```

All image were loaded in listview(100px height and width). I set ImageView.layout_width=70dp and height too.
 but I can't scroll down or up in listview. Because listview is getting so lag and very bad

I think the problem lies is in GetImageBitmapFromUrl. How to fix.

Comment: use imageloader lib best is universalimageloader https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader

Answer (score 1):

You can use [MonoDroid.UrlImageViewHelper](https://github.com/Redth/MonoDroid.UrlImageViewHelper) to load images asynchronously.

```
    if (track.artwork_url != null) {
            viewHolder.Image.SetUrlDrawable(track.artwork_url, Resource.Drawable.img1);
    }
```

You can see more details at Xamarin forum: [ListView - Asynchronous Image Loading (from URL)](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/799/listview-asynchronous-image-loading-from-url)

Comment: where is monoDroid.UrlImageViewHelper. It don't have on internet. I download it on internet but can't add to reference